# Когда надо начинать применять StringBuilder ?

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос, когда (с точки зрения эффективности) выгоднее конкатенировать строки через **StringBuider sb.append()** с последующим **return sb.toString()**, вместо **return "s1"+"s2"...;**

Есть ли у кого-нибудь конкретные замеры производительности ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Компилятор делает это сам, если посмотрите сгенерированный байт-код для конструкций типа s1 + s2 + ..., то там скрытно создаётся StringBuilder, в который пихаются строки.

Comment: Все верно, только с одной оговоркой. Компилятор создает новый экземпляр StringBuilder для каждого составного выражения типа String. Так что если окончательная строка формируется по частям из промежуточных выражений, лучше использовать StringBuilder явно. Ну а если строка формируется целиком в одном выражении, то, действительно, от явного использования StringBuilder никаких бонусов нет, только код сложнее читать.